War movie where a soldier tries to save a drowning person
I recall my uncle talking about this movie a year back but couldn't recall its name. A part of the story is:
An army sets up a base camp in a village of the rival country. They pose as villagers themselves and eventually grow very fond of them. One day someone (a villager) is drowning and one of the soldiers jumps in the water to save him, which causes his clothes to tear and reveal the Nazi (not sure though) symbol which reveals their identity and I am quite unsure what happens next.
I've tried googling this up thinking "drowning" would be a keyword. I couldn't find much (in fact, anything) about the movie though. I think it might be a b/w movie. I'd highly appreciate if someone could tell me the name of the movie. I was moved by the story. 

Pretty sure I know the answer, but I still urge you to add as many details as you remember: year, country\language, possible actors etc. If this is all you remember, I'll put it up.

@Walt I don't remember much. I've tried googling this up thinking "drowning" would be a keyword. I couldn't find much (in fact, anything) about the movie though. I think it might be a b/w movie.  He, of course told me about the actors but I'm very bad with names. I'm sorry. That's all I have.

Pretty sure you're looking for The Eagle Has Landed with Michael Caine, Donald Sutherland and Robert Duvall from 1976.

Colonel Steiner is a German Officer in WW II who has been court-marshaled for opposing the SS in rounding up Jews. He is offered an assignment to go to England and abduct Winston Churchill. His loyal parachute group dress as Polish soldiers and take over a small English town, supposedly on a training maneuver to await the coming visit of the Prime Minister.

Their identity is exposed when one of them tries to save a drowning child, dies in the process and his Nazi uniform is revealed. Here's the trailer:



